# Can't access resources after update to asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

After I've updated from asp.net core 2.0 to 2.1 I can't build the solution anymore. I keep getting errors like

```
CS0117  'Views_Account_Login' does not contain a definition for 'LoginButton'
```

For the update I've followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

This worked fine before. Also when opening the mentioned view, there is no error shown and the mentioned property on the resource does exist.

I tried cleaning/rebuilding, checked that all my resources are actually generated etc.  but without any success so far.

Maybe someone has experienced this problem before?

Update

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
         .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Comment: Did you elect to keep your existing identity code, or did you upgrade to the new UI?

Comment: I didn't touch any code besides the mentioned changes in the upgrade guide (Program and Startup). I think the problem is not related to Identity. The same error appears in every view where I try to access a resource.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App?

Comment: I tried both, with the same result. I started from an empty MVC project, so my code is pretty custom. Basically, what I did before was using localization in views like this @Localizer[nameof(Views_Register_Index.Title)] to not use "magic" strings and have compile time checks. But after the update the compiler complains that those properties are not defined.

Comment: Perhaps you can share your startup code to show `AddLocalization()` and `AddViewLocalization()`.

Comment: Added excerpt from the startup. But I'm not sure it's the root of the problem. Because it's not failing on startup or during execution. But during compilation itself.

Comment: What happens if you add `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` to your project file?

Comment: This solves it, thank you very much! Any idea why it's not working with compile on publish? Something with build order?

Comment: Looks like I was too hasty. Now it just fails on runtime with the same error.

Comment: Could be something to do with your localization.  Have you tried removing it on an affected page to see if it works then?  If so, then check your resources files - for the example you cited it'll either be Resources/Views/Account/Login.en.resx or Resources/Views.Account.Login.en.resx.

Comment: This is really starting to confuse me. The strange thing is, my TestServer integration tests run ok now after compilation was fixed. However, if I want to debug, it fails on runtime. When instead of Localizer[nameof(Views_Register_Index.Title)], I do something like Localizer[LocalizerStrings.Title] where LocalizerStrings is a static class with public static readonly string Title = nameof(Views_Register_Index.Title) it works as well.